# Must declare the scalar variable "@dateofRegister"

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MiniMartSystem.dbConnection.dbConn_local);//(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand register = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Register (firstName,lastName,userName,Password,emailAddress,mobileNo,Department,dateofRegister,Status,registerName) VALUES (@firstName,@lastName,@userName,@Password,@emailAddress,@mobileNo,@Department,@dateofRegister,@Status,@registerName)", conn);

    register.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", tb_firstname.Text);
    register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", tb_lastname.Text);
    register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", tb_loginname.Text);
    register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", tb_passowrd.Text);
    register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailAddress", tb_emailaddress.Text);
    register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobileNo", tb_mobiletno.Text);
    register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", dd_department.Text);
    //register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofRegister", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "True");
    register.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@registerName", MiniMartSystem.dbConnection.username);

    conn.Open();

    try
    {
        //info.Text = "Successfully Register the new user. Please refer Userlist tab from menu ..";

        register.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),
        "MessageBox",
        "alert('Successfully Register the new user. Please refer Userlist tab from menu ..');",
        true);

        tb_firstname.Text = "";
        tb_lastname.Text="";
        tb_loginname.Text="";
        tb_passowrd.Text="";
        tb_emailaddress.Text="";
        tb_mobiletno.Text="";

        conn.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}

private object DateTime()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Please explain what isn't working. As it stands now this is impossible to answer.

Comment: whenever i try to register ...it shows error in line:catch (Exception ex)

Comment: Add an actual question to your question body, it's just a wall of code and a non-descriptive title in it's current form.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't use AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and in particular when a DateTime is involved

Answer (score 1):

You have the line that adds parameter `@dateofRegister` commented out.

```
//register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofRegister", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Comment: when i remove this comment ..the registation page does't even opens

Comment: That is a whole another issue. Please be more specific with your question, and add related code when necessary. There is no mention of "registration page" in your original question. The community cannot help you if you don't include the necessary details.

Comment: @DPac refering to steve's comment, add   `register.Parameters.Add("@dateofRegister", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;` to your answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

You should never pass a value converted to a string to `AddWithValue` when the underlying field to be updated is not a string.

This article explain the details: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

But in short, `AddWithValue` cannot correctly guess the effective datatype required by the parameter in this scenario and decides to use the datatype of the value that you pass to it. In this case a string. But the database field expects a date (or datetime or datetime2 we cannot know from here)

So supposing that you have a `dateofRegister` field of type DateTime then you should add your parameter with

```
register.Parameters.Add("@dateOfRegister", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

without any conversion to a string. Of course this reasoning is valid for all the other fields that are not of text datatype.

Comment: Register.Datetime is not valid in given context

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. Where do you get this message? I have no Register.DateTime in the code above

Comment: Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: As I have said. You should pass values as expected by the underlying fields. You have a varbinary field and you try to pass a string (nvarchar in Sql lingo) for it. Not the same thing. I think that to get out of this you need to add to your question the exact datatype for every field involved in your update (For example firstName  is a nvarchar(100)  ....)